# can i get all facebook pages in my country from graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make an autocomplete search input that allows me to search for any facebook page by name, just like facebook search input,

I could find this link that return pages with defined category 
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=sport&type=page&access_token={}

But I need to even get all the pages which I believe is hard to have, or get all pages in my location or country, or connect direct to Facebook search api and search for the page that I type and return with its result .

Is any of this seems possible?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you can not get a list of all pages. You can get specific search results tailored to the user who's access token is being used, and that's it.

Comment: @CBroe but when i use the above link and for example set q to sport , type page , and add my app access token it will show me result for sport pages , does this mean i will get all sport pages in whole facebook ?

Comment: No, you likely won't. The search endpoint is not meant to provide access to the complete underlying data set.

Comment: CBroe , Thanks for your time